# how to use button as a link?

Tags: php, html, button

Can anyone show me how to use html button as a link to connect to php? I'm not quite sure how to do it and can't find any useful code that can help me to achieve it. I'm pretty new so bit struggling with it.thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDHEN.jpg

```
[![<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-right:60px;
}
</style>
    <title> Washing Machine Control System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BK.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MachineButtons.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor = "Black"> 


<h1>Machine Controller</h1>

    <br></br>
    <br></br>



<form method="GET/POST" action="theNameOfMyPHPFile.php">

<div id="icons"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM1.jpg"  alt="Machine One" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>

        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M1 On" data-off="M1 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>

<div id="icons2"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM2.jpg" alt="Machine Two" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>

        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M2 On" data-off="M2 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>

<div id="icons4"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM3.jpg"  alt="Machine Three" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M3 On" data-off="M3 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>

<div id="icons3"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM4.jpg" alt="Machine Four" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>

        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M4 On" data-off="M4 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
</form>     
</body>
</html>]
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put an `<a>` tag inside a `<button>`?

Comment: You need to post some of your code for us to help you

Comment: what do you mean, "connect to php"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: @MarcB connect to php as in When I press the machine button one, it should push the information such as if the button is ON/OFF to my phpmyadmin database.

Comment: you don't have a phpmyadmin database. phpmyadmin is a management interface. you have a **mysql** database.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I mean the mySql database

Answer (score 1):

While these answers will get you the button, they will not show you how to 'connect' it with PHP. In order to have a button fire PHP code, you must put it in a form and set the form's action to a PHP script. Then, when the form is submitted, it will POST data to the php script you specified. Like so:

**HTML:**

```html
<form action="myscript.php">
    <input type="submit" name="onButton" value="On" />
    <input type="submit" name="offButton" value="Off" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['onButton'])) {
    echo "On button was pressed.";
} else if (isset($_POST['offButton']){
    echo "Off button was pressed.";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Script47 Edited, thanks!

Comment: @MikelBitson Do i have to take out the label tag out for this? and I don't want any text box for this. i only need the button to push the button that is press to php, so php need to add to database if the button is ON/OFF. thanks

Comment: @SunnyRazario Hey there Sunny! I've adjusted my answer to include two submit buttons and the PHP to detect which was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<a href="someurl.php"><button>I\'m a button</button></a>';`

Comment: This shows no interaction with PHP, as was requested in the initial question.

Comment: edited to "interact with php"

Comment: Switched my vote! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
<button onclick="go()">Button</button>


<script>
    function go() {
     window.location.href = "/path/to/url";
    }
</script>
```